# How do I stop Sublime Text converting Sass variables on pressing tab?

Tags: css, autocomplete, sass, sublimetext3, emmet

Does anyone know of a way to prevent Sublime Text 3 converting sass variables on pressing tab?

For example, I might type `$variable-name` and then press tab, intending to insert the `:` and `space`, which would be the normal CSS behaviour. Within doc type sass, I get `1variable-name:;` instead.

It's rather annoying to have to correct every time, and I'm sure others get irritated with the same. I have the Sass and Emmet packages installed.

Many thanks. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the [`Syntax Highlighting for Sass`](https://github.com/P233/Syntax-highlighting-for-Sass) package? I see the same thing too with that plugin, I just wanted to make sure we're both on the same boat.

Comment: actually, upon further investigation, the same thing happens even when the built-in CSS syntax is chosen, so it must be something about Sublime itself. Strange...

Comment: No, I haven't installed Syntax Highlighting package. Just the main "Sass" package. I figured there must be a way to edit the syntax completion in a preferences file, just not sure how. 

It's not a big issue, but when you write code for 8 hours a day, little things like this make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment...

So I did a little digging last night, and from what I can tell this behavior is hard-coded into Sublime. The command that's executed when Tab is pressed right after a variable is `expand_abbreviation_by_tab`. Many times, Sublime commands are implemented in `.py` files, and can so be edited to suit your needs. Unfortunately, I was unable to find any mention of this command anywhere, leading me to believe that it's hard-coded. I suppose a workaround would be to enter a space before hitting Tab, if your end goal is to have the colons `:` aligned with each other. Another option would be to use the [`Alignment`](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment) plugin, available through Package Control. It's very configurable, and I highly recommend it.